# react useState initialValue from api response data? not use useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to initial value from api response data.
after receiving a api response, state should not update.
so, not useEffect..

how to useState initialValue from async api call.

```
  const [state, setState] = useState(async() => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('111');
      }, 2000)
    })
  })
```

Comment: if its an async function that gets your intial state, then its `useEffect` you need.  Either that, or request the data in the parent component and pass default value via props once data has been fetched.  Also, "after receiving a api response, state should not update." doesnt make sense to me, you may need to elaborate a little

Comment: I'm not sure why you're against `useEffect` but that's *exactly* what it's there for. You can give it an empty dependency array to make it only fire once on page load. `useEffect(() => {code here}, [])`

Comment: API call will take some time (probably some 50ms to 10s of seconds ).. so you must show something while the API call is being executed. So the initial state should be undefined, call API in `useEffect` and update your state. Show loading when the state is undefined, later show the data.

Comment: thank you. useEffect must be used  to call async function for initial value.